# Pass facebook access token to server

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, session-variables

my application is a basic php application. I use facebook authentication only for login purposes and have to store basic user information in the database after the user logs in. I also have to set the session variables in php after the user logs in. I plan to use Javascript SDK for the facebook authentication.

**How can I pass the user information after the user has successfully logged in (i.e. "status=connected")  for storage in the database and set the php session variable?**

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook Js SDK sets a cookie in the client browser session that is to be used to get the client access token and other basic user information.